# (index):7272 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated in Flutter and Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-chrome, dart, flutter-web

I am getting this error in chrome console when I deploy my Flutter app to Firebase,

> (index):7272 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

it first loaded the old version of the app but now its throwing me this error and took too long to respond message on chrome page. I tried deleting that firebase channel and created new one but still nothing changes.
Also when I first open my site in chrome incognito mode it worked for the first time but now its also not working...

I also tried deleting my `launch.json` file in vscode thinking that this might the problem cause but still nothing changes.

this web app is also not working in `IOS 12.5.4` so what's causing this problem I ain't able to figure out please help, but my main concern is in windows chrome [this is my web app](https://devcom-ecc99--testing-pw1zbhif.web.app/)
Below is my `index.html` file and I hide my firebase apikeys so ignore that

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- <base href="/"> -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">
  
    <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Devcom">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">
  
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
  
    <title>Devcom</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  </head>
<body>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script> 

<script type="module"> 
   var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "",
      authDomain: "devcom-ecc99.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://devcom.firebaseio.com", 
      projectId: "devcom-ecc99",
      storageBucket: "devcom-ecc99.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "......",
      measurementId: ".......",
      appId: "1:.........:web:........",
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    // const app = initializeApp({ firebaseConfig });
// const app = getAnalytics({ firebaseConfig })    
</script>
 <script>
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
    var scriptLoaded = false;
    function loadMainDartJs() {
      if (scriptLoaded) {
        return;
      }
      scriptLoaded = true;
      var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
      scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js';
      scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
      document.body.append(scriptTag);
    }

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      // Service workers are supported. Use them.
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // Wait for registration to finish before dropping the <script> tag.
        // Otherwise, the browser will load the script multiple times,
        // potentially different versions.
        var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl)
          .then((reg) => {
            function waitForActivation(serviceWorker) {
              serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
                if (serviceWorker.state == 'activated') {
                  console.log('Installed new service worker.');
                  loadMainDartJs();
                }
              });
            }
            if (!reg.active && (reg.installing || reg.waiting)) {
              // No active web worker and we have installed or are installing
              // one for the first time. Simply wait for it to activate.
              waitForActivation(reg.installing ?? reg.waiting);
            } else if (!reg.active.scriptURL.endsWith(serviceWorkerVersion)) {
              // When the app updates the serviceWorkerVersion changes, so we
              // need to ask the service worker to update.
              console.log('New service worker available.');
              reg.update();
              waitForActivation(reg.installing);
            } else {
              // Existing service worker is still good.
              console.log('Loading app from service worker.');
              loadMainDartJs();
            }
          });

        // If service worker doesn't succeed in a reasonable amount of time,
        // fallback to plaint <script> tag.
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (!scriptLoaded) {
            console.warn(
              'Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.',
            );
            loadMainDartJs();
          }
        }, 4000);
      });
    } else {
      // Service workers not supported. Just drop the <script> tag.
      loadMainDartJs();
    }
  </script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated...

thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was one script tag missing in my `index.html` file so first always check your html file for these kind of errors but I also did these below steps.  so make sure you do this if there are no errors in your html file.

Deleting the `widget_test.dart` file did worked for me and

I also deleted auto generated `launch.json` which was created again after deletion.

I was using `flutter_webrtc` with flutter which uses stun and turn servers so I first removed that plugin and all code related to that and reinstalled them later on so I guess improper installation of plugins and wrong html script tags causes this error... I then run `flutter clean` and `flutter create .` and now It's working fine. and when I run usual firebase deploy command it worked out.